# Function PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to do a function with the following sql

This sql converts from numbers to letters

```
With
  Numero as (
  select 3 N from dual
  )
  ,
  PreProcesado1 as (
  select   N
        , floor(mod(N, 10)) Unidades
    from Numero
  )
  select   N,     case Unidades 
                  when 0 then ''
                  when 1 then 'one'
                  when 2 then 'two'
                  when 3 then 'three'
                  when 4 then 'four'
                  when 5 then 'five'
                  when 6 then 'six'
                  when 7 then 'seven'
                  when 8 then 'eight'
                  when 9 then 'nine'
                end
              end
            from PreProcesado1;
```

I’m doing it like this but it doesn’t work, must have an input parameter which in this case is `entry_numero` and which should be converted

```
create or replace function fun_departamento(entry_numero number)
return varchar2 is
response varchar2(120);
begin
  With
      Numero as (
      select entry_numero N from dual
      )
      ,
      PreProcesado1 as (
      select   N
            , floor(mod(N, 10)) Unidades
        from Numero
      )
      select   N,     case Unidades 
                      when 0 then ''
                      when 1 then 'one'
                      when 2 then 'two'
                      when 3 then 'three'
                      when 4 then 'four'
                      when 5 then 'five'
                      when 6 then 'six'
                      when 7 then 'seven'
                      when 8 then 'eight'
                      when 9 then 'nine'
                    end
                  end
                  into response
                  from PreProcesado1; 
return response;
end;
/
```

I get this error, I'd appreciate your help

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Comment: You are trying to select to values and return into one variable. Either remove N in main select, or add one more variable in INTO clause. And I think one redundand END in Case statement exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that you want to do it *your way*, then see lines #16 and #29 as

- line 16: you're selecting two values (`N` and `CASE` expression)
- line 29: you're trying to put 2 values into a single variable (`response`)

Therefore, remove `N` from line #16 (or add another variable to insert into).

```
SQL> create or replace function fun_departamento(entry_numero number)
  2  return varchar2 is
  3  response varchar2(120);
  4  begin
  5    With
  6        Numero as (
  7        select entry_numero N from dual
  8        )
  9        ,
 10        PreProcesado1 as (
 11        select   N
 12              , floor(mod(N, 10)) Unidades
 13          from Numero
 14        )
 15        select
 16                 --  N,                  --> without it! ...
 17                   case Unidades
 18                        when 0 then ''
 19                        when 1 then 'one'
 20                        when 2 then 'two'
 21                        when 3 then 'three'
 22                        when 4 then 'four'
 23                        when 5 then 'five'
 24                        when 6 then 'six'
 25                        when 7 then 'seven'
 26                        when 8 then 'eight'
 27                        when 9 then 'nine'
 28                    end
 29                    into response      --> ... as you're inserting into a single variable
 30                    from PreProcesado1;
 31  return response;
 32  end;
 33  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select fun_departamento(5) from dual;

FUN_DEPARTAMENTO(5)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
five

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler way to do what you need:

```
to_char( to_date(n,'J'),'jsp')
```

For example:

```
SQL> select to_char( to_date(4,'J'),'jsp') as n from dual;

N
----------
four
```

Notice that this does not handle 0, so you may need:

```
select
  case
    when n != 0 then to_char( to_date(n,'J'),'jsp')
  end
from ...
```

[Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650) you find something more.

Comment: okay it is valid, but if I want to follow the structure of the question?

Comment: If you follow the OP's question closely, you will notice that the input can be any number (not just an integer between zero and nine). In his code, he rounds the number, and then takes the remainder mod 10. Your solution should do the same. Separately: I see the question as a generic one about how to transform a SQL statement, as is, into a PL/SQL wrapped statement. If that was the OP's main reason to ask the question (and apparently it was), then your solution won't help him.